# When Spark call Hive from oozie, exception raised "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException"

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, oozie, hcatalog

I have spark job that save data to hdfs then it save the same data to Hive table. When I run it on Jupyter, it run succesfully. But when I run it through oozie It raises the folloing exception when it reaches the step of writing data to hive.
Here is my code followed by the exception and followed by workflow .xml:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[10]:


import os

JARS_HOME = "hdfs:///dataengineering/jars"
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars '+JARS_HOME+'/ojdbc6.jar,'+JARS_HOME+'/anonymize_udfs.jar pyspark-shell'

os.environ["HADOOP_CONF_DIR"] = '/etc/hadoop/conf'


# In[11]:


try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
except:
    import findspark
    findspark.init('/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.1.1-1.cdh6.1.1.p0.875250/lib/spark')
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import sys
import pyspark.sql.functions as functions
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta  
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType



spark = SparkSession.builder     .master("yarn")     .appName("oozie_sample_spark")     .config('spark.executor.cores','3')     .config('spark.executor.memory','15g')     .config('spark.driver.memory','5g')     .config('spark.driver.maxResultSize','12g')    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")    .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")    .config("spark.executor.instances", "4")    .config("spark.yarn.queue", "root.STREAMING")    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.cachedExecutorIdleTimeout", "300s")    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://dchqmaster01.internal.eg.vodafone.com:9083")    .getOrCreate()


# In[13]:


spark.sql("select current_timestamp() column_a").write.csv("/user/akhamis11/oozie-samples/spark-sample/current_column.csv", mode='append')


spark.sql("select current_timestamp() column_a").write.saveAsTable("bde.oozie_test", mode='append')


spark.stop()
```

---

```
2020-04-13 07:27:21,077 [dispatcher-event-loop-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator  - Driver requested a total number of 0 executor(s).
2020-04-13 07:27:21,081 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter  - Write Job 316245be-4c54-42d9-bd43-6246d77672b0 committed.
2020-04-13 07:27:21,108 [Thread-10] INFO  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter  - Finished processing stats for write job 316245be-4c54-42d9-bd43-6246d77672b0.
2020-04-13 07:27:21,191 [Thread-10] INFO  com.cloudera.spark.lineage.NavigatorQueryListener  - Failed to generate lineage for successful query execution.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.query.analysis.QueryAnalysis$.hiveCatalog(QueryAnalysis.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.query.analysis.QueryAnalysis$.getLineageInfo(QueryAnalysis.scala:88)
    at com.cloudera.spark.lineage.NavigatorQueryListener.onSuccess(ClouderaNavigatorListener.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$onSuccess$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$onSuccess$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$util$ExecutionListenerManager$$withErrorHandling$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$util$ExecutionListenerManager$$withErrorHandling$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:143)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager.org$apache$spark$sql$util$ExecutionListenerManager$$withErrorHandling(QueryExecutionListener.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$onSuccess$1.apply$mcV$sp(QueryExecutionListener.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$onSuccess$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager$$anonfun$onSuccess$1.apply(QueryExecutionListener.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager.readLock(QueryExecutionListener.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ExecutionListenerManager.onSuccess(QueryExecutionListener.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:189)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/HiveException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:73)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 45 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/disk10/yarn/nm/usercache/akhamis11/appcache/application_1586733850175_0103/container_1586733850175_0103_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/disk10/yarn/nm/usercache/akhamis11/appcache/application_1586733850175_0103/container_1586733850175_0103_02_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o148.saveAsTable.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveSessionStateBuilder$$externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.tableExists(SessionCatalog.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:400)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:189)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/HiveException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:73)
    ... 26 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oozie_sample_spark.py", line 53, in <module>
    spark.sql("select current_timestamp() column_a").write.saveAsTable("bde.oozie_test", mode='append')
  File "/disk10/yarn/nm/usercache/akhamis11/appcache/application_1586733850175_0103/container_1586733850175_0103_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 775, in saveAsTable
  File "/disk10/yarn/nm/usercache/akhamis11/appcache/application_1586733850175_0103/container_1586733850175_0103_02_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/disk10/yarn/nm/usercache/akhamis11/appcache/application_1586733850175_0103/container_1586733850175_0103_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: "Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':"
```

---

```
<action name='spark-node'>

    <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:1.0">
        <resource-manager>${resourceManager}</resource-manager>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <configuration>
       <property>
      <name>oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark</name>
      <value>spark2</value>
    </property>
       <property>
      <name>oozie.service.HCatAccessorService.hcat.configuration</name>
      <value>/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>            
        <master>${master}</master>
        <name>oozies_sample</name>
        <jar>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/oozie-samples/spark-sample/lib/oozie_sample_spark.py</jar>

    </spark>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>

<kill name="fail">
    <message>Workflow failed, error
        message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
    </message>
</kill>
<end name='end' />
```

---

```
[~]$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/HikariCP-java7-2.4.12.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/accessors-smart-1.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/activation-1.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/annotations-2.0.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/antlr4-runtime-4.7.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/aopalliance-1.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/arrow-format-0.10.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/arrow-memory-0.10.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/arrow-vector-0.10.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/avro-ipc.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/avro-mapred-hadoop2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/avro.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.271.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/azure-keyvault-core-0.8.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/azure-storage-5.4.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/breeze-macros_2.11-0.13.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/breeze_2.11-0.13.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/chill-java-0.9.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/chill_2.11-0.9.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-cli-1.4.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-codec-1.10.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-compiler-3.0.9.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-configuration2-2.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-crypto-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-io-2.6.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-lang-2.6.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-lang3-3.7.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-math3-3.4.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-net-3.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/commons-pool-1.6.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/core-1.1.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/curator-client-2.7.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/datanucleus-core-4.1.6.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/derby-10.14.1.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/ehcache-3.3.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/flatbuffers-1.2.0-3f79e055.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/flume-ng-config-filter-api-1.8.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/flume-ng-configuration-1.8.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/flume-ng-core-1.8.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/flume-ng-sdk-1.8.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/geronimo-jcache_1.0_spec-1.0-alpha-1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/gson-2.2.4.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/guava-11.0.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/guice-4.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/guice-servlet-4.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-annotations.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-auth.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-aws.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-azure-3.0.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-client-3.0.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-common.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-hdfs-client.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-openstack-3.0.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-yarn-api.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-yarn-client.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-yarn-common.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-yarn-server-common.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hive-common.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hive-exec.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hive-hcatalog-core.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hive-hcatalog-pig-adapter.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hive-metastore.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hive-serde.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hive-site.xml
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hive-webhcat-java-client.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/hppc-0.7.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/htrace-core4-4.1.0-incubating.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/httpclient-4.5.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/httpcore-4.4.6.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/ivy-2.4.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-annotations-2.9.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-core-2.9.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.9.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13-cloudera.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-module-paranamer-2.9.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jackson-module-scala_2.11-2.9.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/janino-3.0.9.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/javax.inject-1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jcip-annotations-1.0-1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jersey-client-2.22.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jersey-common-2.22.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jersey-container-servlet-2.22.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jersey-media-jaxb-2.22.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jersey-server-2.22.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jetty-jmx-9.3.20.v20170531.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jetty-util-9.3.20.v20170531.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jetty-util-ajax-9.3.20.v20170531.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jetty-webapp-9.3.20.v20170531.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jetty-xml-9.3.20.v20170531.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/joda-time-2.9.9.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jodd-core-3.5.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jsch-0.1.54.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/json-smart-2.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/json4s-ast_2.11-3.5.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/json4s-core_2.11-3.5.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/json4s-jackson_2.11-3.5.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/json4s-scalap_2.11-3.5.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jsp-api-2.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jtransforms-2.4.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kafka-clients-2.0.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerb-admin-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerb-client-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerb-common-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerb-core-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerb-crypto-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerb-identity-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerb-server-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerb-simplekdc-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerb-util-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerby-asn1-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerby-config-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerby-pkix-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerby-util-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kerby-xdr-1.0.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/kryo-shaded-4.0.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/libfb303-0.9.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/libthrift-0.9.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/log4j-1.2.17.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/lz4-java-1.4.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/machinist_2.11-0.6.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/macro-compat_2.11-1.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/metrics-core-3.1.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/metrics-graphite-3.1.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/metrics-json-3.1.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/metrics-jvm-3.1.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/mina-core-2.0.4.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/minlog-1.3.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/netty-3.10.6.Final.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/netty-all-4.1.17.Final.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/nimbus-jose-jwt-4.41.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/objenesis-2.5.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/okhttp-2.7.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/okio-1.6.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/oozie-sharelib-spark-5.0.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/oozie-sharelib-spark.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/opencsv-2.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/oro-2.0.8.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/paranamer-2.8.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/parquet-column.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/parquet-common.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/parquet-encoding.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/parquet-format.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/parquet-hadoop.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/parquet-jackson.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/py4j-0.10.7.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/pyrolite-4.13.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/pyspark.zip
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/re2j-1.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/scala-compiler-2.11.12.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/scala-library-2.11.12.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.1.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/scala-reflect-2.11.12.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.5.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/shapeless_2.11-2.3.2.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/snappy-java-1.1.4.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-avro_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-catalyst_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-core_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-graphx_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-hadoop-cloud_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-hive_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-kvstore_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-launcher_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-lineage_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-mllib-local_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-mllib_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-network-common_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-network-shuffle_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-repl_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-sketch_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-sql_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-streaming-flume_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-streaming_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-tags_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spark-yarn_2.11-2.4.0-cdh6.1.1.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spire-macros_2.11-0.13.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/spire_2.11-0.13.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/stream-2.7.0.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/univocity-parsers-2.7.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/wildfly-openssl-1.0.4.Final.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/woodstox-core-5.0.3.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/xbean-asm6-shaded-4.8.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/xz-1.6.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/zookeeper.jar
/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_<ts>/spark2/zstd-jni-1.3.2-2.jar
```

Comment: Are you using CDH? please provide the workflow.xml you are using in oozie.

Comment: yes I am using CDH 6.1.1 parcels. for the workflow.xml, I added it in the main thread above.

Comment: I remember we face a problem to run spark2 with oozie untill we create new spark2 action. 
1. please edit the post so the error stacktrace will be readable. 
2. what jars /user/oozie/share/lib/<timestamp>/spark2 directory contains? which jars you put there?

Comment: I added the libraries above and formatted the log ... please note that I had added  libraries in the following link: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.3.1/DG_HCatalogIntegration.html#HCatalog_Libraries and I am testing it ... if you can advise about it or another solution

Comment: It gives me another error now
`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory`

Comment: I`m not familiar with this guide, back in times i was able to do it after a lot of problems (but it was a while ago), this exception obviously is occuring because you missing some jars, after checking org.apache.commons.dbcp.ConnectionFactory is belong to commons-dbcp.jar that is not on the list. You should add it (ssh to one of your servers and just exec 'locate commons-dbcp'), after u add it don't forget to restart oozie.

Answer (score 0):

`Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog'` This means the `Catalog` jar, its trying find is not in ooziesharelib spark directory.

Please add the following property in your job.properties file.

```
oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark=hive,spark,hcatalog <spark2 instead of spark if you are using cloudera>
```

This will allow hive jars to use in spark action. For external hive catalog spark oozieShareLib dirctory does not contain every jars.

org/apache/commons/dbcp/ConnectionFactory releated jar lives under hive lib folder.
So please check weather the jar exists in your local file system as well as in hdfs

`find <location> -name "*.jar" | xargs grep ConnectionFactory`

Also please add this in your SparkSession to enable hive support for spark sql `.enableHiveSupport()`